# Terraform module reference can not resolve

Tags: github, terraform, devops, infrastructure-as-code

I have a Terraform structure as follows:

```
├── main.tf
├── team-members
│   ├── github-team-memberships-Admin.tf
│   └── main.tf
├── teams
    ├── github-teams-Admin.tf
    └── main.tf
```

The content of my main.tf file in the root directory is as follows:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    github = {
      source  = "integrations/github"
      version = "~> 5.0"
    }
  }
}


module "teams" {
  source = "./teams"
}

module "team_members" {
  source = "./team-members"
}
```

The content of my github-teams-Admin.tf file under the teams directory is as follows:

```
resource "github_team" "Admin" {
  name           = "Admin"
  description = "Admin team"
  privacy        = "closed"
  parent_team_id = null
}
```

The content of my main.tf file in the team-members directory is as follows:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    github = {
      source  = "integrations/github"
      version = "~> 5.0"
    }
  }
}

module "teams" {
  source = "../teams"
}
```

The content of my github-team-memberships-Admin.tf file in the team-members directory is as follows:

```
resource "github_team_membership" "Admin-XXXX" {
  username    = "XXXX"
  team_id     = module.teams.github_team.Admin.id
  role        = "member"
}
```

When I try to reference resources from the team-members directory to the resources in the teams directory, I receive the following error:

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on team-members/github-team-memberships-Admin.tf line 3, in resource "github_team_membership" "Admin-XXXX":
│    3:   team_id     =  module.teams.github_team.Admin.id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.teams is a object
│ 
│ This object does not have an attribute named "github_team".
```

Where am I making a mistake? How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: In addition to the answer from @Marcin, I'd suggest you probably don't want two instances of the `teams` module, but rather to pass its outputs into `team_members` as a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your module `teams` located in  `"../teams"`, you have to define an output `github_team`, e.g.

```
output "github_team" {
   value = "<github_team-value>"
}
```